# Unable to call a function inside a class in Python

Tags: python

I am learning Python. I am getting this error when I attempt to call a function which is inside the class. So please help me to fix this.

```
tony@kali:~$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class H:
...            def y():
...                  print "j"
... 
>>> g=H
>>> g.y()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method y() must be called with H instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> H.y()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method y() must be called with H instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>>
```

Comment: You should use `g = H()` to get an instance of a class.

Comment: You created a method. Why do you need to call it as a function? You don't *have* to use a class in Python, just don't put it in a method. Otherwise, use the `staticmethod` decorator, but then you have a class without state.

Comment: @luoluo: that's only part of the problem, there is no `self` argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, a reference for you https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes

Comment: A general comment is that your post would benefit from some formatting and cleaning up. This would be inviting and nice to the people who donate their time freely to you. But such process would also help to get things more clearly for yourself

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the `class`, then only you can call the methods of that `class`. Also, methods should have it's first argument as `self`.

```
class H:
   def y(self):
         print "j"
g = H()
g.y()
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) for more details about self.

You should definitely check [this chapter](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) for class.

Answer (score 0):

You've got answers and comments, so let me explain the error message.

In your code, `g` and `H` are different names for the same thing, so the two errors are one.

Now, `H` is an (old-style) class and all the functions `def`'ed below it, unless "processed" with tricks like `classmethod` or `staticmethod`, are methods.  When you access the methods as attributes of the *class* `H`, they're known as "unbound" methods because they're not yet bound to an *instance* of the class `H`.

To understand how Python's core model of classes, methods, and attributes, I recommend the excellent posts by Shalabh Chaturvedi:

- [Python Types and Objects](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html)
- [Python Attributes and Methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html)

The tl;dr version: normally you're expected to call a method by invoking an instance's *bound* method:

```
>>> class H(...):
>>>     def y(...):
>>> h_instance = H()
>>> h_instance.y(...)
```

Python will put that instance (`h_instance` here in the fake code snippet) as the first argument to the method.  If you call it as `h_instance.y()`, the actual argument list is `(h_instance)`; if you call it as `h_instance.y(a)`, the arguments are `(h_instance, a)`.

This is why you almost invariably find the first formal argument in a method definition to be `self`.  There's nothing special about this name, except that Python expects that slot be reserved for the instance on which the method is invoked.  It *allows* you to define the method with an empty argument list, but that one wouldn't be useful when you actually use the instance.  In that case you'll always get `TypeError` -- because the call sends ONE argument (the "`self`" instance) while there's none in the method definition.

As a demonstration, consider the following session:

```
In [1]: class H(object):    # New-style class, doesn't matter here.
   ...:     def y(self):    # Notice the call signature: "self" included
   ...:         print "j"        

In [2]: h_instance = H()    # Create an instance from the class

# This is how normally you're expected to call. There's no argument
# passed to the *bound* to the instance h_instance, because when you do
# this Python will carry out the syntactic desugaring and call on the
# instance.
In [3]: h_instance.y()
j

# This does the same thing and demonstrates the concept of an
# unbound method.  It's not bound to any specific instance of H, so
# you'll have to specify which instance to call.
In [4]: H.y(h_instance)
j
```